# Not able to create covered query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java, nosql

I am facing problem to create covered query. I am using Mongo 3 latest version. Here is my sample data which I have inserted 10006 documents into MongoDB.

```
db.order.insert({ _id: 1, cust_id: "abc1", ord_date: ISODate("2012-11-02T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "A", amount: 50 })
db.order.insert({ _id: 2, cust_id: "xyz1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-10-01T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "A", amount: 100 })
db.order.insert({ _id: 3, cust_id: "xyz1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-10-12T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "D", amount: 25 })
db.order.insert({ _id: 4, cust_id: "xyz1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-10-11T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "D", amount: 125 })
db.order.insert({ _id: 5, cust_id: "abc1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-11-12T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "A", amount: 25 })
```

For Covered Query, All the fields in the query are part of an index so I have created index for status, ord_date, cust_id and amount fields like :

```
db.orders.createIndex({status: 1})
db.orders.createIndex({amount: 1})
db.orders.createIndex({ord_date: 1})
db.orders.createIndex({cust_id: 1})
```

I have executed following query.

```
          db.orders.find(
                 {status : "A"},{ord_date : 1, cust_id : 1}
          ).sort({ amount: -1 }).explain()
```

But This explain query returns executionStats.totalDocsExamined = 200 instead of  executionStats.totalDocsExamined = 0. means it is scan documents when I execute query. In Mongo 3, We can check index covered a query using executionStats.totalDocsExamined instead of indexOnly.

Can anyone please suggest me what I am doing wrong in covered query ?

Here is my output after index suggestion by Markus:

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "local.orders",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "status" : {
            "$eq" : "A"
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
        "transformBy" : {
            "_id" : 1,
            "ord_date" : 1,
            "cust_id" : 1
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "amount" : -1
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "status" : {
                        "$eq" : "A"
                    }
                },
                "direction" : "forward"
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 10004,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 70,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 10018,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
        "nReturned" : 10004,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 70,
        "works" : 20026,
        "advanced" : 10004,
        "needTime" : 10021,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "saveState" : 157,
        "restoreState" : 157,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "transformBy" : {
            "_id" : 1,
            "ord_date" : 1,
            "cust_id" : 1
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "nReturned" : 10004,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 70,
            "works" : 20026,
            "advanced" : 10004,
            "needTime" : 10020,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "saveState" : 157,
            "restoreState" : 157,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "sortPattern" : {
                "amount" : -1
            },
            "memUsage" : 960384,
            "memLimit" : 33554432,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "status" : {
                        "$eq" : "A"
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 10004,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                "works" : 10020,
                "advanced" : 10004,
                "needTime" : 15,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "saveState" : 157,
                "restoreState" : 157,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "docsExamined" : 10018
            }
        }
    },
    "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "pcd32",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.0.7",
    "gitVersion" : "6ce7cbe8c6b899552dadd907604559806aa2esd5"
}
```

}

Comment: please show complete output of `.explain()`

Comment: I have updated my output in my question.

Answer (score 1):

While there are [index intersections in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/), they can be quite tricky to utilize. However, sticking to a rule of thumb is a rather safe bet:

> When creating queries MongoDB, assume that only one index can be used at a time

This is especially true for [covered queries](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query), as detailed in the docs:

> An index covers a query when both of the following apply:
>
> - all the fields in the query are part of an index, and
> - all the fields returned in the results are in the same index.

Having a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/) doesn't have drawbacks, when carefully crafted, as queries using only parts of that index can use it, too.

So in order to make your query covered, you need to have **all** keys you want to return in your index. Since you did not [limit the fields returned](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#limit-fields-to-return-from-a-query) ("projection" in MongoDB terms), I assume you need the `_id` field to be returned as well. Furthermore, your index should reflect your sorting order. So your index should look like:

```
db.orders.createIndex({_id:1,status:1, ord_date:1,cust_id:1,amount:-1})
```

*for your query*. Order matters, so in order to make best use of the newly created index, other queries should adhere to the same order of fields.

Comment: I have created only "db.orders.createIndex({_id:1,status:1, ord_date:1,cust_id:1,amount:-1})" index according my return fields. But still result seems executionStats.totalDocsExamined = 200 instead of 0. May I need to create any other indexes except your index ?

Comment: @sus007 Please add the output of "yourQuery.explain()" after you created the index to your question.

Comment: I have created index like that : 
db.orders.createIndex({status: 1, amount: 1, ord_date: 1, cust_id: 1});
and I solved this problem. So order of field in index is very important for covered query.

Comment: Markus, I have tried with your suggested index but it will not return 0 value for totalDocsExamine in explain method.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the output of your queries ".explain()"

Comment: I have create another question regarding covered query. so please check it. Thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345030/how-to-create-covered-query-index-in-mongodb

Comment: I have updated my post with new .explain() output after creating index as you suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

If you also need the `_id` field, then the below compound index should give you a covered query:

```
 db.order.createIndex({status:1, amount:-1, ord_date:1, cust_id :1, _id:1})
```

If you don't need the `_id` field then use `_id : 0` in the `find()`, so that _id is not retrieved and you can remove it from the index as well.
Note that in a covered query, ordering of the fields as compared to the actual query being executed is important for the index to be used in the execution of the query.

Comment: I have create another question regarding covered query. so please check it. Thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345030/how-to-create-covered-query-index-in-mongodb